# Is specific heat really a constant?

Tags: thermodynamics

When we calculate heat lost or gained by a body according to equation $q=mc\Delta T$ where

- $m$ = mass of body
- $c$ = specific heat
- $\Delta T$ = temperature difference

In this equation, why do we take $c$ to be constant because we know $c$ depends on temperature? Why is the equation not $q=m\int c\Delta T$?

Comment: Please use MathJax to write formulas or formula-like objects. It really improves your questions.

Comment: Because c is a constant over small (to even large) temperature ranges.

Comment: for water if t=(15.5-16.50)(degree)celcius c=1cal/g/k. I dont think it is a large temp. range

Comment: Yes that is a small range and 1 is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

No, specific heat varies with temperatures. Only at temperatures way beyond the Debye temperature is the specific heat of the body a constant. This equation treats the specific heat as a constant because the temperature range of operation is assumed to be small enough for a constant assumption of specific heat. The final data that you get will not have as much noise as you are expecting. This equation is more of an engineering equation than that of physics. The original equation is much more complicated, and solving practical engineering problems using the original equation would be unnecessarily difficult. The general variation is such that at temperature much lower than the debye temperature, the specific heat has a cubic dependence and at temperatures much higher the dependence is constant.